# how to solve java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JList$3 cannot be cast to javax.swing.DefaultListModel

Tags: java

I'm building a new application when I run the application this exception arise and this my class.

```
 private void userPermession(){
 try {
     DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
     String sql="select * from userMenu order by menuno";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
          while(rs.next()){
          String m = rs.getString("menuName");
          model.addElement(m);
          }
          lstMenu.setModel(model);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex, "Error", HEIGHT);
    }  
}
```

Comment: This looks like a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/19145200/4722577

Comment: Always include the full stack trace and show exactly what line in your code is referenced.

Comment: What line causes the exception?

Comment: I don't know because program is not running and throw exception.